# How to move image on fixed path on user scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made this [piping demonstration](https://radiant-retreat-42716.herokuapp.com/) as an example for what I'm trying to do. The piping and background colors span 3 divs, and I have a small glowing ball that I would like to move along the piping as the user scrolls the page down. On the horizontal portions of the piping, I would like to create an expanding div, but first things first, here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.canvas {
background-image: url(/images/piping_demonstration2.png);
}
#glow {
background-image: url(/images/glow.png);
background-attachment: fixed;
}
.dadiv {
height: 500px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<section class="canvas">
    <div id="glow">

<div id="first" class="dadiv" height="500px"></div>

<div id="second"class="dadiv" height="500px"></div>

<div id="third" class="dadiv" height="500px"></div>

</div>

</section>

</body>
</html>
```

I understand that I will have to use JavaScript, but I have not yet been able to find a good source to start.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am looking for a similar animation.

Comment: @RhythmRuparelia I have not. I gave up shortly after I realized it was going to take more time than I thought something like that should, and I haven't revisited it since.

Comment: I had made it working now, still need to make it responsive. I have a project where the object moves on zigzag path in desktop view, but path changes to straight line in mobile view. I am using GSAP (greensock) for animation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jQuery plugin **Scrollpath**: http://joelb.me/scrollpath/.

It's no longer maintained but the source code (https://github.com/JoelBesada/scrollpath) should make a good starting point.